# Images on buttons in loops in tkinter

Tags: python, image, loops, button, tkinter

I have read every answer to this I can possibly find and nothing seems to be working.
I am making all my buttons in a loop.  When I run the program my grid shows up correctly but the buttons don't click and the images don't show.
I have tried: 
disabling garbage collection
adding buttons and images to a list
assigning the buttons and images to attribute of my Item class

inside my function that makes my UI I have this function:

```
def make_item_buttons():
    #gc.disable()
    row_position=2
    col_position=1
    i=2
    but=tk.Button()
    for newitem in self.itemlist:
        if(col_position > 4):
            i+=1
            col_position=1
            row_position=i
        but = tk.Button(self, name=newitem.get_name().lower(),command=lambda: [shop(newitem.get_name()), press()])
        but.config(image=newitem.tkImage(), width=200, height=200, bg="black")
        but.image = newitem.tkImage()
        but.grid(row=row_position, column=col_position)
        self.notgarbage.append(but)
        #self.notgarbage.append(but.image)
        newitem.set_button(but)
        #newitem.setimagelbl(but.image)
        col_position+=1
```

I do know that is if I comment out :

> but.config(image=newitem.tkImage(), width=200, height=200, bg="black")

I get small buttons that do click and do their functions, but no image and the wrong size

newitem is a object of Class Item below
the Item Class:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Item:

    def __init__(self, name, imagefile, price):
        self.imagefile=imagefile
        self.button=None
        self.name=name
        self.price=price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def tkImage(self):
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.imagefile)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_price(self):
        return float(self.price)
    
    def change_price(self,newprice):
        self.price=newprice
    
    def set_button(self,button):
        self.button=button
    
    def setimagelbl(self,image):
        self.imagelbl=image
```

Comment: As `def make_item_buttons()` has no argument, so it may not be a class method.  So what is `self` in the code?  Also no information on the type of `newitem`.

Comment: its not a class method it does not need self it is a function inside of a class method.  Updated code to show Item Class

Comment: That's why [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required.

Comment: Everytime `Item.tkImage()` is called, a new instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` is created and returned.  So `but.config(image=newitem.tkImage(),...)` and `but.image = newitem.tkImage()` refer to different instances of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`.

Comment: Thanks you that was my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the problem found by acw1668:

> Everytime `Item.tkImage()` is called, a new instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` is created and returned. So `but.config(image=newitem.tkImage(),...)` and `but.image = newitem.tkImage()` refer to different instances of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`.